# SOAP request is not working for special character ~

Tags: java

I have a soap request like this

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://secbrupdtreq.xsd">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <sec:UpdateRequest>
             <sec:SourceName>ACES</sec:SourceName>
             <sec:AgmntXrefBusKey>001~0011256482196</sec:AgmntXrefBusKey>
             <sec:IndividualAgreementId></sec:IndividualAgreementId>
             <sec:CustomerRolePlayerId></sec:CustomerRolePlayerId>
             <sec:AnnualIncomeAmt></sec:AnnualIncomeAmt>
             <sec:RiskToleranceCode></sec:RiskToleranceCode>
             <sec:RiskToleranceCodeTxt></sec:RiskToleranceCodeTxt>
             <sec:Occupation></sec:Occupation>
             <sec:NASDAffiliation></sec:NASDAffiliation>
             <sec:NetWorthCode></sec:NetWorthCode>
             <sec:NetWorthCodeTxt></sec:NetWorthCodeTxt>
             <sec:DeclaredNetWorthAmt></sec:DeclaredNetWorthAmt>
             <sec:LastSuitabilityReviewDt></sec:LastSuitabilityReviewDt>
             <sec:SuitabilityInScopeFlag></sec:SuitabilityInScopeFlag>
             <sec:SuitabilityOutofScopeReasonCode></sec:SuitabilityOutofScopeReasonCode>
             <sec:SuitabilityOutofScopeReasonTxt></sec:SuitabilityOutofScopeReasonTxt>
             <sec:CreationTs></sec:CreationTs>
             <sec:SUSAgreementId></sec:SUSAgreementId>
             <sec:CategoryId1>45</sec:CategoryId1>
             <sec:CategoryId2></sec:CategoryId2>
             <sec:CategoryId3></sec:CategoryId3>
          </sec:UpdateRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

In soap ui I am getting

> "org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified".

I am using **Java 1.8**.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the xml-header with encoding type of your request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```